# android regular expression to get strings from content returned from url

Tags: regex

I need to extract name and image location from this strings. I need to do it with android code. Can anyone suggest a regular expression to do that?

```
binu.h@xmail.com|::break::|binu|::break::|uploads/images/1234.jpg|::break::|2322|::endline::|boss@xmail.com|::break::|boss biju|::break::|uploads/vfd.jpg|::break::|7687|::endline::|
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove '::break::|'
fill a String array by splitting at '|'.
Take the index you need.

Or first split at '::endline::', second split at'::break::', take the indexes you need.